# How can I recover from a package management failure?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 17.04

Recently I've been unable to install or remove software packages on Ubuntu 17.04.

I run `sudo apt update` successfully with the last line of output reading:

```
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

So I followed up with `sudo apt upgrade` :

```
sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dev libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib
  python3.5 python3.5-dev python3.5-doc python3.5-minimal
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 49.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 18.4 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [413 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [37.7 MB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5 amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [1,372 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python3.5 amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [175 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5-stdlib amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [2,167 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python3.5-minimal amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [1,635 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5-minimal amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [529 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python3.5-doc all 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1 [5,295 kB]
Fetched 49.3 MB in 24s (1,993 kB/s)                                            
(Reading database ... 1108124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-python3.5-dev_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5-dev (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libpython3.5-dev_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-libpython3.5_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-python3.5_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-python3.5-minimal_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libpython3.5-minimal_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-python3.5-doc_3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3.5-doc (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) over (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.0) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python3.5-doc (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for dochelp (0.1.4) ...
E: /usr/share/doc-base/diveintopython-zh: Field "translator" is not allowed in section Document
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 8 changed doc-base files, 2 added doc-base files...
Error while merging /usr/share/doc-base/inform-docs-dm4 with /usr/share/doc-base/inform-docs-ibg: format pdf already defined.
Registering documents with dwww...
Registering documents with dhelp...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up emacs25 (25.1+1-3ubuntu4.1) ...
Install cmake-data for emacs25
install/cmake-data: Byte-compiling for emacs25
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/cmake-data/cmake-mode.el': File exists
Install emacsen-common for emacs25
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs25
Install php-elisp for emacs25
install/php-elisp: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50devhelp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Info: Skip debian-el loading if run under dpkg control.
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionary-el.el (source)...
Loading dictionary-init...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gforth.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gnu-smalltalk-el.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gnugo.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp-keybindings.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50lookup-el.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50mdk.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50php-elisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pspp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pylint.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/60cltl.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/60hyperspec.el (source)...
Install pspp for emacs25
install/pspp: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50devhelp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Info: Skip debian-el loading if run under dpkg control.
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionary-el.el (source)...
Loading dictionary-init...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gforth.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gnu-smalltalk-el.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gnugo.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp-keybindings.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50lookup-el.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50mdk.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50php-elisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pspp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50pylint.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/60cltl.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/60hyperspec.el (source)...
Install pylint for emacs25
install/pylint: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Install lookup-el for emacs25
install/lookup-el: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Install mdk for emacs25
install/mdk: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Install dictionaries-common for emacs25
install/dictionaries-common: Already byte-compiled for emacs25. Skipping ...
Install gforth for emacs25
install/gforth: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
Install gnu-smalltalk-el for emacs25
install/gnu-smalltalk-el: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
cp: cannot create symbolic link './gst-mode.el' to '../../../emacs/site-lisp/gnu-smalltalk-el/gst-mode.el': File exists
cp: cannot create symbolic link './smalltalk-mode.el' to '../../../emacs/site-lisp/gnu-smalltalk-el/smalltalk-mode.el': File exists
ERROR: install script from gnu-smalltalk-el package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.5-dev:amd64 (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.5-dev (3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

emacs25 was **not** one of the 8 packages to be upgraded.  Upon further inspection of the output, line 11 reports that 1 package is not fully installed or removed.  I'm guessing this is the emacs25 package.

So, the 8 upgradeable packages cannot be upgraded.  Further, I cannot remove the emacs25 package (nor any other).  Also, I cannot install any new packages (nor emacs25).

How do I recover from this package management fiasco?

Comment: I have never seen this type of problem before, but if I were you, and simply going by the error messages, I would go in and rename the files that it is complaining about already existing.  However this may be a symptom of a deeper permissions problem.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the "not fully installed package" and then remove it? (`sudo apt install --reinstall ...`)?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelBay.  I have tried to install emacs25... but, as I said, sudo apt install AND sudo apt remove fail because of the twisted shape of the package database.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f`... And I clearly mentioned reinstall (with the `--reinstall` argument).

Comment: I'll try that, @OrganicMarble... and will update when I've completed.

Comment: @MichaelBay, I run "sudo apt install -f --reinstall emacs 25" and I get:

E: Internal Error, No file name for emacs25:amd64

Comment: You mixed two different commands for different purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66371/discussion-between-thegeeko61-and-michaelbay).